# Loopback API Explorer authentication

Tags: node.js, loopback

I have created a new project in Loopback Node.js
I'm concerned with the API being public. As when I will deploy the project on server then the URL containing the API's will be accessible easily. Hence I wanted to restrict anyone to use the API's and it should be used from Android devices which has my front-end app.
I do not understand the User model that is already created since there isn't any specific file for this model, so I am creating my own userauth model, but again the same concern that it will be accessed by everyone when deployed on the main server.

Comment: I would highly recommend having a look at the [loopback docs on authentication, authorization, and permissions](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Authentication%2C+authorization%2C+and+permissions). That will give you a good place to start and it might also help you narrow down your question. In it's current state, your question is a little too broad for me to be able to provide a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding API endpoints getting public, I would suggest either of the following (I use 2nd one):

1) Using ACLs to restrict usage to specific end points
Use can specifiy the acls in the model classes individually which you want to restrict access to.

If you want to implement a common acl to every model then I would suggest you inherit the **Persisted Model** i.e create MyBaseModel with base as "PersistedModel". Then in all your models use base model as "MyBaseModel"

2) Using a middleware which checks if request is made from android app

In your android app set some header for every request to your server such as 
`httpConnection.setRequestProperty("MyCustomProperty", "ThisIsFromAndroidApp");`

Then in your Loopback server's **boot scripts** create a middleware which checks for this:

```
module.exports = function(app){
    app.use(function(req, res, next){
      if(req.headers["MyCustomProperty"] === 'ThisIsFromAndroidApp'){
         return next();
      }
      res.json({err: "Unauthorised access to api endpoint"});
   });
}
```

Now for the built in User model:
You can find this their User model in *node_modules\loopback\common\models\user.js*

Loopback authentication uses a mix of functions from **access_token.js** (AccessToken model) and **user.js** (User Model). You can find both these models in

*node_modules\loopback\common\models\*

Comment: Perfect @Jibin Thanx